# Problema no código do meu buscador

Tags: java, android

Como não consigo usar o searchview decidi usar um edittext e uma logica q achei em um forum, mas passo por dificuldades tem alguma ideia?

[image: imagem do código com o erro]

### MainActivity.class

```
public void CarregarEncontrados()
{

   int textlength = et.getText().length();

   //Limpa o array com os estados encontrados
   //para poder efetuar nova busca
   lstEstados_Encontrados.clear();

   for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++)
   {
       if (textlength <= item.get(i).getResId())
       {
           //Verifica se existe algum item no array original
           //caso encontre é adicionado no array de encontrados
           if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String)item[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
           {
               lstEstados_Encontrados.add(item.get(i));
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O que eu entendi da sua pergunta é que você está com problema na linha 129 da imagem.

Se realmente for isso, acredito que o problema seja que você tenta acessar um elemento da `ArrayList` com `[]`, porém o correto é com o `get(int index)`, ou seja, similar ao que você faz na linha 125.

Answer (score 0):

Tente substituir por este código:

**Exemplo**

```
public void CarregarEncontrados()
{

   int textlength = et.getText().length();

   //Limpa o array com os estados encontrados
   //para poder efetuar nova busca
   lstEstados_Encontrados.clear();

   for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++)
   {
       if (textlength <= item.get(i).getResId())
       {
           //Verifica se existe algum item no array original
           //caso encontre é adicionado no array de encontrados
           if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(item.get(i).subSequence(0, textlength)))
           {
               lstEstados_Encontrados.add(item.get(i));
           }
       }
   }
}
```